# Is storing sensitive info via SFTP any less secure than via SOAP?

Tags: soap, security, sftp

Is a file transferred via SFTP any less secure than the same data transferred via SOAP into a database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by SFTP and DB. SFTP as an acronym usually refers to the "Secure File Transfer Protocol". DB normally refers to a "database." These are two entirely different things.

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded my question differently. Is a file transferred via SFTP any less secure than the same data transferred via SOAP into a database?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? Are you just concerned of the transfer or also about the storage afterwards? For the transfer: SFTP uses an encrypted connection, while SOAP data is transferred via HTTP or HTTPS, so it *can* be encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

SFTP is very secure.  The "S" in "SFTP" even stands for secure.  That doesn't mean that a file transferred via SFTP is necessarily secure, of course -- just that if something goes wrong with the security, you probably have something else to blame *other* than SFTP.  SFTP won't be the weak link.  You could still have a weak password, lose your certificate, have the secret service raid your data center, etc.

However, SOAP has nothing to do with security.  A SOAP request is a *thing* which can be secure or insecure depending on how it's sent.  If you send SOAP over HTTP, it is *incredibly* insecure.  If you send it over HTTPS, it can be relatively secure depending on how much you trust your CA.  Using SOAP over HTTP is like leaving your UPS package on the doorstep.  It's convenient but someone could walk by and take it.

Think about it this way: SOAP is the money, HTTPS is the armored car.  Except sometimes the armored car is driven by the Chinese government to a completely different location, unless you have a rule in place to prevent that from happening.  (Google Chrome, for example, uses a whitelist for CAs on specific domains.)

**Summary:**

- SFTP is secure, if you get your certificates right.
- SOAP over HTTPS is secure, if you get your certificates right.
- SOAP over HTTP or SMTP is **insecure.**

Getting your certificates right is the only hard part about this.